# AngularJS: transcluded with same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that wraps another one like this :

```
<div direction from="origin" to="destination">
    <div direction-map line-color="#e84c3d"></div>
</div>
```

the `direction-map` directive is transcluded, see my code ([Fiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/w4ew650s/1/)) :

```
var directionController = function() {
    //do stuffs
};
var directionMapController = function() {
    //do other stuffs
};
var Direction = angular.module("direction", [])
    .controller("directionController", directionController)
    .controller("directionMapController", directionMapController)
    .directive("direction", function() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "AEC",
            controller: "directionController",
            scope: {},
            transclude: true,
            link: {
                pre: function($scope, $element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
                    console.log("direction's controller is directionController : ");
                    console.log(controller.constructor === directionController);//true, that's ok
                    transclude($scope, function(clone) {
                        $element.append(clone);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        return directive;
    })
    .directive("directionMap", function() {
        var directive = {
            require: "^direction",
            controller: "directionMapController",
            restrict: "AEC",
            scope: true,
            link: {
                pre: function($scope, $element, $attrs, controller) {
                    console.log("directionMap's controller is directionMapController :");
                    console.log(controller.constructor===directionMapController);//false that's not OK!!!!
                }
            }
        };
        return directive;
    });
```

So my question is:

Why my child directive `direction-map` gets as parameter the controller of its parent (I think it's because it is transcluded), is it possible to avoid this or should I just re-think my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening beacause you are using `require: "^direction"` if you remove this line the directive will get the controller of itself rather than the parent one.

Hope it help :)

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v32975fy/)

Comment: ok, it works, but actually, direction is required to make it works, so I'd like to understand why, any idea ?

Comment: ok got it, found in angular docs:
"When a directive uses this option, $compile will throw an error unless the specified controller is found. The ^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on its parents (without the ^ prefix, the directive would look for the controller on just its own element)."